# Laravel cronjob schedule command not firing on production

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.6

I have 7 different schedule commands on kernel.php and one of those is not firing when running the schedule.

```
kernel.php
....
$schedule->command('my:command')->hourlyAt(15); // this wont run
...
```

Running `php artisan my:command` manually on command line works fine.

Also when running the scheduler on our dev server, all commands works fine. The problem is only on production server.

There are no errors on log files.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I'm using Laravel 5.6

---

UPDATED:
The problem was wrong artisan path on laravel forge scheduler

Comment: Did you add the crontab on the server ? Did you check the command executed is correct, with the right path ?

Comment: the problem was wrong artisan path on laravel forge scheduler

Comment: Very well so ! That’s always tricky, and it lt’s Always worth to double check executing the command manually, or even better use absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

Have you add following cron entry as per your project folder path ?

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

please check with following commands

```
crontab -l
```

If not ?

open crontab by

```
crontab -e
```

add * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 entry at the end of file

save file and run following commands

```
sudo service cron restart
```

again check with crontab -l

this command will return already set cronjob

i hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Check timezone configs of your server and scheduled tasks as well. I haven't set the time zones on the tasks, and by default it was set to UTC. You can verify when the jobs should run by:

`php /path/to/project/artisan schedule:list`

```bash
  40 22 * * *  App\Jobs\SomeJob ...... Next Due: 6 minutes from now
  40 6  * * *  App\Jobs\SomeJob ........ Next Due: 8 hours from now
  40 14 * * *  App\Jobs\SomeJob ....... Next Due: 16 hours from now
```