# Scheduler in Laravel Forge not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel

As per the Forge documentation regarding task scheduling with Laravel scheduler, I have set up a schedule on forge with the command

```
php8.1 /home/forge/default/artisan schedule:run
```

User is forge and frequency is set to every minute

My keneral.php has a schedule that is supposed to go off only right before midnight at whichever timezone it is for the user. However, when the scheduler runs on forge it seems like the command is getting executed every minute instead of checking what the schedule function has to say about it.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $users = User::all();


        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $timezone = $user->timezone;


            $schedule->command('nullDay:daily')->timezone($timezone)->between('23:50', '23:58');
        }
    }
```

This schedule function works great in local when running `schedule:work` so I tried use that instead of `schedule:run` in the forge command input but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the output when I have the `php8.1 /home/forge/default/artisan schedule:run` with the kernal code above:

`[2022-01-06T20:07:02+00:00] Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php8.1' 'artisan' nullDay:daily > '/dev/null' 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Try it might work

```
cd /home/forge/default && php8.1 artisan schedule:run
```

Might also follow

1. https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/scheduler.html
2. https://mattstauffer.com/blog/laravel-forge-scheduling-a-cron-job/
3. https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/laravel-scheduler-cpanel-cron-job

Comment: still doesn't work, I tried this with both schedule:run and schedule:work

Comment: Few more reference added, check might help

Comment: There could be timezone issues as well - check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123527/6696949